# How to access to list of all ansible extra-vars, passed from the cli? (Variable of variable)

Tags: ansible

I have a problem with accessing to extra-vars from my playbook with variable-of-variable way.
For example, I created a group_vars/mygroup.yml file with content:

```
MYVAR=AAAA
```

Then I call command and pass extra-vars:
    ansible-playbook -i test playbook.yml --extra-vars "MYVAR=BBB"

I need to get actual value of MYVAR from list of exists variables. I tried to do this:

```
- debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]['MYVAR']
```

...I getting

```
TASK: [test | debug var=AAA] *******************************
ok: [192.168.1.21] => {
    "var": {
        "AAA": "BBB"
    }
}

TASK: [test | debug var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]['AAA']] ***
ok: [192.168.1.21] => {
    "var": {
        "hostvars[inventory_hostname]['AAA']": "AAA"   // ← THIS IS THE PROBLEM
    }
}
```

How I can get actual value of AAA, that passed from cli?
Please, *don't say to me to just use AAA directly by name*, because this is a part of more complex logic, when I have a list of registered variables and I can't use their names.

```
hostvars[inventory_hostname][**item**] ← variable of variable
```

Thank you in advance.

Update: **OR** maybe Ansible already supports something like this?:

```
VARNAME: APP_ENV
APP_ENV: blabla
debug: var=${VARNAME} // blabla expected
```

Update 2: The [github gist](https://gist.github.com/KIVagant/bf33525ffea1def0186d) with problem explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, after ansible 2.0 was released, [the problem from gist example](https://gist.github.com/KIVagant/bf33525ffea1def0186d) is gone:

```
ansible-playbook -i localhost.ini test.yml --extra-vars="AAA=BBB"
TASK [debug]     *****************
ok: [localhost] => (item=AAA) => {
    "item": "AAA",
    "msg": "BBB"
}
```

So, like [@chrism said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34414710/how-to-access-to-list-of-all-ansible-extra-vars-passed-from-the-cli-variable#comment56580517_34419462), it was a bug.

Comment: what is the exact code in your playbook that is producing this output ?

Comment: Sorry, the code is from 2016. I don't have the infrastructure and the playbook anymore.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; `- debug: msg="{{ AAA|default(hostvars[inventory_hostname]['AAA']) }}"` Use variable `AAA` when it's defined, else use the hostvar (groupvar) `AAA`

```
#./main.yml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ foo }}"
    - debug: msg="{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['foo'] }}"
    - debug: msg="{{ foo|default(hostvars[inventory_hostname]['foo']) }}"
```

.

```
#./inventory
[one]
localhost ansible_connection=local
```

.

```
#./group_vars/one
---
foo: "bar"
```

`ansible-playbook -i inventory -e "foo=whatever" main.yml`

```
PLAY [all] ********************************************************************

TASK: [debug msg="{{ foo }}"] *************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "whatever"
}

TASK: [debug msg="{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['foo'] }}"] *****************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "bar"
}

TASK: [debug msg="{{ foo|default(hostvars[inventory_hostname]['foo']) }}"] ****
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "whatever"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: Thank you, but all variables registered inside list. I have only {{ item }} key from list:

        hostvars[inventory_hostname][item]

Comment: @kivagant looks like this may be a bug with 1.9 ish. https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/9667 2.0 behaves the way you want (extra-vars are set as hostvars). I tested with 2.0 myself.

Comment: Bug that is represented by your link looking very similar. Especially this commit https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/e61e8a37f50860534610ef767315d70ba61583a2
But I have 1.9.4 and extravars does not overriding hostvars in my case. 
I will wait for 2.0 stable in OSX packages for testing, but now I need to find some not clever way to work around the error.

Comment: Finally, the release 2 was published but at the moment Ansible 2 has new errors with variables.
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/14067

Answer (score 0):

command line extra defines are not part of hostvars.

You can access that through `{{ MYVAR }}`

```
- debug: msg="{{ MYVAR }}"
```

Comment: `- debug: var=MYVAR` or `- debug: msg="{{ MYVAR }}"`

Comment: Thank you, but all variables registered inside list. I have only {{ item }} key from list: hostvars[inventory_hostname][item] and I can't call it directly by name.